# Chamar JavaScript no PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estou iniciando no PHP e sou técnico em VB.NET e MYSQL. A única linguagem que não tenho afinidade é o JavaScript e PHP.

Tenho uma dúvida onde preciso chamar uma notificação na index.php.

O script é esse [Notify](http://bootstrap-notify.remabledesigns.com/) e estou tentando fazer com que ela apareça. Meu arquivo está assim:

[image: Código do index.php]

E eu quero chamar essa notify: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

porém me retorna esse erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém pode me explicar como eu adiciono o script? Independente de qual seja, só preciso entender como faço a chamada. Obrigado

Comment: Java não é JavaScript. São duas coisas diferentes.

Comment: A sim, então estou falando de Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está usando um código JavaScript dentro de um bloco PHP (`<?php ?>`). Deve colocar o código dentro da tag script:

```
<script>
  // código aqui
</script>
```

Porém é preciso também que o arquivo do plugin seja carregado antes do código:

```
<script src="/not/bootstrap-notify.min.js"></script>
<script>
  // código aqui
</script>
```

Vai precisar também carregar o jQuery antes de todas as bibliotecas. Exemplo:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/not/bootstrap-notify.min.js"></script>
<script>
  // código aqui
</script>
```

Comment: Já estava digitando que não estava carregando, mas com o jquery que você pediu pra adicionar deu certo. Valew ! Deu certinho.

Só uma dúvida, caso eu queira chamar essa notificação após clicar em um button eu chamo ela como?

Comment: seria algo assim: `$("button").click(function(){ $.notify({ opções aqui  }) });`... onde "button" pode ser uma class, id etc.. para identificar o botão clicado

Comment: Deu certo Sam, consegui fazer a chamada. Toda vez que eu for executar o script eu tenho que chamar a tag <script src="/not/bootstrap-notify.min.js"></script> ? Não tem como eu definir essa tag em um lugar da pagina que sempre é acessivel? Pois o código ficaria mais limpo...

Comment: Vc só coloca isso `<script src="/not/bootstrap-notify.min.js"></script>` só uma vez na página para carregar o plugin.

Comment: sempre acima do primeiro lugar que vou utilizar né?

Comment: Não necessariamente. Vc pode organizar os scripts que vão ser carregados no <head>, por exemplo